# Hive query to find the count for the weeks in middle

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like below

```
id      week    count   
A100    201008  2    
A100    201009  9    
A100    201010  16    
A100    201011  23    
A100    201012  30    
A100    201013  36    
A100    201015  43    
A100    201017  50    
A100    201018  57    
A100    201019  63    
A100    201023  70    
A100    201024  82    
A100    201025  88    
A100    201026  95    
A100    201027  102
```

Here, we can see that below weeks are missing :

- First 201014 is missing
- Second 201016 is missing
- Third weeks missing 201020, 201021, 201022

My requirement is whenever we have missing values we need to show the count of previous week.

In this case output should be :

```
id      week    count
A100    201008  2    
A100    201009  9    
A100    201010  16    
A100    201011  23    
A100    201012  30   
A100    201013  36    
A100    201014  36    
A100    201015  43    
A100    201016  43    
A100    201017  50    
A100    201018  57    
A100    201019  63    
A100    201020  63
A100    201021  63    
A100    201022  63    
A100    201023  70    
A100    201024  82    
A100    201025  88    
A100    201026  95    
A100    201027  102
```

How I can achieve this requirement using hive/pyspark?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information about what you're looking to do. Are you talking about weeks in the year? Why doesn't it start from week 0? Do you want to go up to week 52 or up to 53 (like ISO-8601)? Do you want it per group?

Comment: @pault It is not supposed to start with zero  ( although it can ) . Week columns consists of fiscal week number .201009 means 9th fiscal week of year 2010

Answer (score 3):

Although this answer is in `Scala`, Python version will look almost the same & can be easily converted.

**Step 1:**

Find the rows that has missing week(s) value prior to it.

Sample Input:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//sample input
val input = sc.parallelize(List(("A100",201008,2), ("A100",201009,9),("A100",201014,4), ("A100",201016,45))).toDF("id","week","count")

scala> input.show
+----+------+-----+
|  id|  week|count|
+----+------+-----+
|A100|201008|    2|
|A100|201009|    9|
|A100|201014|    4| //missing 4 rows
|A100|201016|   45| //missing 1 row
+----+------+-----+
```

To find it, we can use `.lead()` function on `week`. And compute the difference between the `leadWeek` and `week`. The difference should not be > 1, if so there are missing row prior to it.

```
val diffDF = input
  .withColumn("leadWeek", lead($"week", 1).over(Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"week")))   // partitioning by id & computing lead()
  .withColumn("diff", ($"leadWeek" - $"week") -1)                                 // finding difference between leadWeek & week

scala> diffDF.show
+----+------+-----+--------+----+
|  id|  week|count|leadWeek|diff|
+----+------+-----+--------+----+
|A100|201008|    2|  201009|   0| // diff -> 0 represents that no rows needs to be added
|A100|201009|    9|  201014|   4| // diff -> 4 represents 4 rows are to be added after this row.
|A100|201014|    4|  201016|   1| // diff -> 1 represents 1 row to be added after this row.
|A100|201016|   45|    null|null|
+----+------+-----+--------+----+
```

**Step 2:**

- If the diff is >= 1: Create and Add n number of rows(`InputWithDiff`, check the case class below) as specified in
  `diff` and increment `week` value accordingly. Return the newly
  created rows along with the original row.
- If the diff is 0, No additional computation is required. Return the original row as it is.

Convert `diffDF` to Dataset for ease of computation.

```
case class InputWithDiff(id: Option[String], week: Option[Int], count: Option[Int], leadWeek: Option[Int], diff: Option[Int])

val diffDS = diffDF.as[InputWithDiff]

val output = diffDS.flatMap(x => {
 val diff = x.diff.getOrElse(0) 

 diff match {
  case n if n >= 1 => x :: (1 to diff).map(y => InputWithDiff(x.id, Some(x.week.get + y), x.count,x.leadWeek, x.diff)).toList  // create and append new Rows
  case _ => List(x)      // return as it is
 }
}).drop("leadWeek", "diff").toDF   // drop unnecessary columns & convert to DF
```

final output:

```
scala> output.show
+----+------+-----+
|  id|  week|count|
+----+------+-----+
|A100|201008|    2|
|A100|201009|    9|
|A100|201010|    9|
|A100|201011|    9|
|A100|201012|    9|
|A100|201013|    9|
|A100|201014|    4|
|A100|201015|    4|
|A100|201016|   45|
+----+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

**PySpark solution**

Sample Data

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,201901,10),
                            (1,201903,9),
                            (1,201904,21),
                            (1,201906,42),
                            (1,201909,3),
                            (1,201912,56)
                           ],['id','weeknum','val'])
df.show()
+---+-------+---+
| id|weeknum|val|
+---+-------+---+
|  1| 201901| 10|
|  1| 201903|  9|
|  1| 201904| 21|
|  1| 201906| 42|
|  1| 201909|  3|
|  1| 201912| 56|
+---+-------+---+
```

1) The basic idea is to create a combination of all id's and weeks (starting from the minimum possible value to the maximum) with a `cross join`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import min,max,sum,when
from pyspark.sql import Window
min_max_week = df.agg(min(df.weeknum),max(df.weeknum)).collect()
#Generate all weeks using range
all_weeks = spark.range(min_max_week[0][0],min_max_week[0][1]+1)
all_weeks = all_weeks.withColumnRenamed('id','weekno')
#all_weeks.show()
id_all_weeks = df.select(df.id).distinct().crossJoin(all_weeks).withColumnRenamed('id','aid')
#id_all_weeks.show()
```

2) Thereafter, `left join`ing the original dataframe on to these combinations helps identify missing values.

```
res = id_all_weeks.join(df,(df.id == id_all_weeks.aid) & (df.weeknum == id_all_weeks.weekno),'left')
res.show()
+---+------+----+-------+----+
|aid|weekno|  id|weeknum| val|
+---+------+----+-------+----+
|  1|201911|null|   null|null|
|  1|201905|null|   null|null|
|  1|201903|   1| 201903|   9|
|  1|201904|   1| 201904|  21|
|  1|201901|   1| 201901|  10|
|  1|201906|   1| 201906|  42|
|  1|201908|null|   null|null|
|  1|201910|null|   null|null|
|  1|201912|   1| 201912|  56|
|  1|201907|null|   null|null|
|  1|201902|null|   null|null|
|  1|201909|   1| 201909|   3|
+---+------+----+-------+----+
```

3) Then, use a combination of window functions, `sum` -> to assign groups
and `max` -> to fill in the missing values once the groups are classified.

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy(res.aid).orderBy(res.weekno)
groups = res.withColumn("grp",sum(when(res.id.isNull(),0).otherwise(1)).over(w1))
w2 = Window.partitionBy(groups.aid,groups.grp)
missing_values_filled = groups.withColumn('filled',max(groups.val).over(w2)) #select required columns as needed
missing_values_filled.show() 

+---+------+----+-------+----+---+------+
|aid|weekno|  id|weeknum| val|grp|filled|
+---+------+----+-------+----+---+------+
|  1|201901|   1| 201901|  10|  1|    10|
|  1|201902|null|   null|null|  1|    10|
|  1|201903|   1| 201903|   9|  2|     9|
|  1|201904|   1| 201904|  21|  3|    21|
|  1|201905|null|   null|null|  3|    21|
|  1|201906|   1| 201906|  42|  4|    42|
|  1|201907|null|   null|null|  4|    42|
|  1|201908|null|   null|null|  4|    42|
|  1|201909|   1| 201909|   3|  5|     3|
|  1|201910|null|   null|null|  5|     3|
|  1|201911|null|   null|null|  5|     3|
|  1|201912|   1| 201912|  56|  6|    56|
+---+------+----+-------+----+---+------+
```

**Hive Query with the same logic as described above (assuming a table with all weeks can be created)**

```
select id,weeknum,max(val) over(partition by id,grp) as val
from (select i.id
            ,w.weeknum
            ,t.val
            ,sum(case when t.id is null then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by i.id order by w.weeknum) as grp 
      from (select distinct id from tbl) i
      cross join weeks_table w
      left join tbl t on t.id = i.id and w.weeknum = t.weeknum
     ) t
```